# SQL Genius need .. Complex MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimise my php by doing as much work on the MySQL server as possible.  I have this sql query which is pulling data out of a leads table, but at the same time joining two tags tables to combine the result.  I am looking to add a company which is linked through a relations table.

So the table that holds the relationship between the two is relations_value which simply states (I add example data)

> parenttable (companies) | parentrecordid (10) | childtable (leads) | childrecordid (1)

the companies table has quite a few columns but the only two relevant are;

> id (10) | companyname (my company name)

So this query currently grabs everything I need but I want to bring the companyname into the query:

```
SELECT leads.id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.tag ORDER BY c.tag) AS tags, 
       leads.status, 
       leads.probability
  FROM `gs_db_1002`.leads
          LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * 
                        FROM tags_module 
                        WHERE tagid IN ( SELECT id 
                                           FROM tags 
                                           WHERE moduleid = 'leads' ) ) as b 
                 ON leads.id = b.recordid
          LEFT JOIN `gs_db_1002`.tags as c 
                 ON b.tagid = c.id
 GROUP BY leads.id,
          leads.status, 
          leads.probability
```

I need to be able to go into the relations_values table and pull parenttable and parentrecordid by selecting childtable = leads and childrecordid = 1 and somehow join these so that I am able to get companyname as a column in the above query...

Is this possible?

I have created a sqlfiddle: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/023fa/2 So I am looking to add companies.companyname as column to the query.

Comment: Can you create a small sample of your data on a http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: ... and edit the sample with the desired result into your question please.

Comment: I have created a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/023fa/2  So I am looking to add companyname as column to the query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your primary keys and foreign keys are that link each table together.. if you could give a better understanding of what ID's are linked to eachother it would make this a lot easier... however i did something that does return the correct result... but since all of the ID's are = 1 then it could be incorrect.

```
SELECT 
    leads.id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.tag ORDER BY c.tag) AS tags, 
    leads.status, leads.probability, companyname
FROM leads
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM tags_module WHERE tagid IN ( 
        SELECT id FROM tags WHERE moduleid = 'leads' ) 
    ) as b ON leads.id = b.recordid
LEFT JOIN tags as c ON b.tagid = c.id
LEFT JOIN relations_values rv on rv.id = b.recordid
LEFT JOIN companies c1 on c1.createdby = rv.parentrecordid
GROUP BY leads.id,leads.status, leads.probability
```

Comment: Unfortunately that wont work.  But many thanks for the attempt.  

What connects leads to companies is the relation in the relations_values table.  So childmodule (leads) and childrecoridid (1) will identify the correct table parentmodule (companies) and parentrecordid (2).  So now we know that we need to go to companies andf pull companies.id = 2.  Does this help?

(I have removed the id from relations_values to prevent confusion)

Comment: so when childmodule = 'leads' it is a row related to the leads table? does childrecordid have any relation to another table? I can't see the updated fiddle because the link changes

Comment: No relation to any other table, just leads

Comment: Well if the record is called form parent it needs to know who the child is.  So the child can call the parent and the parent can call the child.

Comment: I understand that... im aking what is the child linked to? which table?